# Proving the probability integral transform without assuming that the CDF is strictly increasing

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

I know that the proof of the [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) has been given multiple times on this site. However, the proofs I found use the hypothesis that the CDF $F_X(x)$ is strictly increasing (together, of course, with the hypothesis that $X$ is a continuous random variable). I know that actually the only required hypothesis is that $X$ is a continuous random variable, and strict monotonicity is not required. Can you show me how?

Since I'm already here, I also take the occasion to ask for a simple application of the probability integral transform :) can you show me that, if $X$ has CDF $F_X(x)$ and $Y$ is the truncation of $X$ to $[a,b]$, then $Y$ is distributed as  $F_X^{-1}(U)$ where $U\sim[F_X(a),F_X(b)]$?

Comment: if you would be so kind, in the proof of your link, could you point to where the requirement that $F_X(x)$ has to be strictly increasing. Thanks!

Comment: @Erosennin, the proof assumes the existence of the inverse of $F_X(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! But is there ever a CDF that is not strictly increasing? You have probably already thought of this, though...

Comment: Of course there is. The random variable whose pdf is equal to 1/2 in [0,0.5], 0 in [0.5,1] and 1/2 in [1,1.5], has a CDF which is continuous, but is not strictly increasing.

Comment: The hard part is dealing with the non-absolutely continuous part of $F$. The idea is made clear by considering the extreme case of discrete $F$.  At http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36246/919 I give an algorithm that implements the probability integral transform in that case (as well as supplying working code). Emulating that algorithm for arbitrary $F$ will answer your question.

Comment: @Erosennin consider any discrete random variable for example - F is a step function, which is not strictly increasing.

Comment: thanks guys , @Glen_b bit emberrased I didnt think of discrete distributions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the wikipedia link provided by the OP, the probability integral transform in the univariate case is given as follows

> Suppose that a random variable $X$ has a continuous distribution for which the cumulative distribution function(CDF) is $F_X$. Then the random variable $Y=F_X(X)$ has a uniform distribution.
>   **PROOF**
>   Given any random variable $X$, define $Y = F_X (X)$. Then:
>
> $$ \begin{align} F_Y (y) &= \operatorname{Prob}(Y\leq y) \\
>          &= \operatorname{Prob}(F_X (X)\leq y) \\
>          &= \operatorname{Prob}(X\leq F^{-1}_X (y)) \\
>          &= F_X (F^{-1}_X (y)) \\
>          &= y \end{align} $$
>
> $F_Y$ is just the CDF of a $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ random variable.
>   Thus, $Y$ has a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 1]$.

The problem with the above is that it is not made clear what the symbol $F_X^{-1}$ represents. If it represented the "usual" inverse (that exists only for bijections), then the above proof would hold only for continuous *and* strictly increasing CDFs. But this is not the case, since for any CDF we work with the quantile function (which is essentially a generalized inverse),

$$F_Z^{-1}(t) \equiv \inf  \{z : F_Z(z) \geq t \}, \;\;t\in (0,1)$$

Under this definition the wikipedia series of equalities continue to hold, for continuous CDFs. The critical equality is

$$\operatorname{Prob}(X\leq F^{-1}_{X} (y)) = \operatorname{Prob}(X\leq \inf  \{x : F_X(x) \geq y \})= \operatorname{Prob}(F_X (X)\leq y)$$

which holds because we are examining a continuous  CDF. This in practice means that its graph is continuous (and without vertical parts, since it is a function and not a correspondence). In turn, these imply that the [infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) (the value of inf{...}), denote it $x(y)$, will always be such that $F_X(x(y)) = y$. 
The rest is immediate.

Regarding **CDFs of discrete (or mixed) distributions,** it is not (cannot be) true that $Y=F_X(X)$ follows a uniform $U(0,1)$, but it is still true that the random variable $Z=F_{X}^{-1}(U)$ has distribution function $F_X$ (so the inverse transform sampling can still be used). A proof can be found in [Shorack, G. R. (2000). Probability for statisticians](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387989532). **ch.7**.

Comment: +1 A similar proof is also provided on pg. 54 of Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference, second edition.

Comment: @Analyst1 Thanks, it's good to have multiple references.