# Is it possible to transform probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, continuous-data, feature-engineering

Let's say I have a real dataset. One of the "Features" let call it X1 follows Weibull distribution.Can I change X1 distribution from Weibull to exponential or to any continuous distribution log normal ,Gamma etc..

Is it possible ?

Comment: [Transforming a distribution into another one?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409351/transforming-a-distribution-into-another-one)

Comment: Sorry its not clear.

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: It doesn't provide information about the thing I requested

Comment: Are you sure? Have you read gunes's answer from that post? It looks to me like it answers exactly your question.

Comment: Alright  Thank you

Comment: Details can be found by searching our site for [probability integral transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+integral+transform). These posts show that when $X$ is a random variable with continuous distribution function $F_X(x)=\Pr(X\le x),$ then $F_X(X)$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1].$ When $F_Y$ is another distribution function, then $Y=F_Y^{-1}(F_X(X))$ is a random variable with distribution $F_Y.$ *This solution is not unique,* but it at least is monotonically non-decreasing.